# Directory listing over SSH

Tags: shell, ssh, directory, ls

I'm looking for a directory listing over SSH to a remote machine.  I want to list only directories sorted by date descending and return just the directory name with the most recent date.....

I tried:

```
ssh user@ftp.zacks.com "find ./ -type d -maxdepth 1 | ls -lt | head -2 | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial testing:

```sh
ls -dtl */
```

prints only directories with their properties like permissions, newest time first (you can reverse the order with the `-r` switch).

However, just to add, if you want just one line, the simplest print of directories:

```sh
echo */
```

But you want it sorted, so the first choice is for you.

---

But, if I understand your question correctly, you want 1 (one) newest directory name only.

```sh
ls -dt1 */ | head -1
```

Something like this I would use for that.

Comment: @LandonStatis No problem, if the answer solved your issue, please do not forget to accept it. Cheers!